# htaccess // allow only certain file or folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm currently rebuilding my site and I want to make "under construction" page for visitors during that time.

My only problem is that I want to user pictures whit it but when I have in my htaccess file this:

```
# Under construction
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/rebuilding\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://www.myurl.com/rebuilding.html [R=302,L]
```

visitors have access only that rebuilding.html file, but no other right? So how can I manage to solve that?
But all files in one folder and redirect all but myself into there? How?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 3):

Put the maintenance files in a separate directory and restrict access to files within that directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this was a `give-me-teh-codez` question.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow all media types (css, png, gif, jpg) with yet another rewrite cond. And no matter which folder they are in - they will be loaded.